# Play constantly writes to disc? Causing higher bill on Amazon ec2

Tags: java, linux, scala, amazon-ec2, playframework-2.0

I've got myself an Amazon ec2 Micro Instance (A VPN Server) to play around with.
The problem is that Amazon charge you for every disc IO you do in a Micro Instance.
The instance is running Amazon Linux a flavor of CentOS.

I've started a Scala application in Play 2.0(.2) framework on the server and I'm the only one who connects to the application.

I have observed that every few second something on the server commits IO transactions, to narrow it down I installed a Linux program called `iotop`.

Here is an output after a couple of seconds.

```
TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    
23333 be/4 root        0.00 B/s   11.91 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 %  
COMMAND java -Dsbt.ivy.home=/usr/play-2.0.2/framework/../repository -Djava.runtime.name=OpenJDK ~/jars/slf4j-api.jar:/usr/play-2.0.2/repository/local/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.6.4/jars/j
```

A cat from the log file

```
cat /home/ec2-user/socketTest/logs/application.log
2012-07-05 11:43:31,881 - [INFO] - from play in main
Listening for HTTP on port 9000...
```

So Play doesn't write anything to the log file.

First question have I understood the iotop correct and that Play indeed is the disc IO thief.
If so why do play use IO?

My application is a simple websocket example. In essence it echos the input to the output. The IO occurs even thou nothing is pushed thru websockets.

Comment: Are you launching your Play! server using sbt (ie `play run` or `play start`) or are you using the start script generated by `play dist` ?

Answer (score 30):

I've finally found the answer.

By observing when Play made an IO transaction I instantly executed this command:

```
touch -d '-10 seconds' /tmp/newerthan
find / ! -fstype proc -newer /tmp/newerthan
```

This returned one interesting line:

```
/tmp/hsperfdata_root/23320
```

While googling on this i stumbled upon a Bug ID: 5012932 from sun [JVM creates subdirectory "hsperfdata_xxx"](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5012932). Java does this to enable noninvasive observability
of the JRE, they claim it's a feature and not a bug that's why it hasn't been resolved.
A solution presented to disable this "feature" was to make use of an undocumented option `-XX:-UsePerfData`. I tried this but unfortunately Play kept making the IO transactions.

But after some more digging I found another switch `-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem`.

So I executed `export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem"` before starting Play .

And... Voilà Play stopped making the IO transactions!

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to know *which* files are being written to, you can use `inotifywait`, which is shipped in the `inotify-tools` package (at least that's what Fedora calls it):

```
$ inotifywait -r -m /opt /etc /var -e ATTRIB -e CREATE -e MODIFY -e DELETE
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.
/var/tmp/ CREATE etilqs_uOXWfa8v7DkNBgd
/var/tmp/ DELETE etilqs_uOXWfa8v7DkNBgd
/var/tmp/ MODIFY etilqs_uOXWfa8v7DkNBgd
/var/tmp/ MODIFY etilqs_uOXWfa8v7DkNBgd
/var/tmp/ MODIFY etilqs_uOXWfa8v7DkNBgd
  ...
```

Obviously, replace "/opt /etc /var" above with whatever directories you suspect are interesting.

It's almost certainly much more efficient than running `lsof` in a loop and grepping its output.  But you probably shouldn't leave it running for a long time in production.

Anyway, once you know which files are being written to, you'll be well on the way to stopping it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also recursively `ls` your directory and sort by `atime` (or`mtime` or whatever)

Answer (score -2):

Yet another solution (simple but useful):

```
# watch df
```

Then you can run this to go deeper:

```
# du -s /your/path/
```